# AngularJS partials in Jade using boolean attributes

Tags: angularjs, pug

I am using AngularJS together with Jade. Suppose I have a "partial" as follows.

```
h1 State 1
div(ui-view)
```

This is a standalone Jade file, and the problem is when it is compiled, since it is not specified a doctype, it compiles into the following.

```
<h1>State 1</h1>
<div ui-view="ui-view"></div>
```

The boolean option `ui-view` being mirrored into `ui-view="ui-view"` is problematic for AngularJS. AngularJS do not recognize it if it is mirrored. The problem lies within Jade, because I did not specify `doctype html`, so Jade does not know it is HTML5 and hence the problem. On the other hand, it is a "partial" and I cannot specify `doctype` inside it.

I use Grunt to compile everything and it seems I am not able to specify an option through Grunt to Jade.

How can I get this `ui-view` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in an options object when you call your jade compile or render and include `{doctype: 'html'}`